# Import class from another file in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have `main.js` and `logParser.js` both in the same folder:

The logParser.js is:

```
let logParser = {
    loadFile = function () {
        console.log("file loaded.");
    };
};

export default logParser;
```

The main.js is:

```
import logParser from './logParser.js';
init = function () {
    logParser.loadFile();
}

init();
```

The problem is that I get `SCRIPT1086: Module import or export statement unexpected here` error in main(1,1);

How do I go about importing that class in main?

PS: The answer from the "duplicate" question does not work: If I add `type="module"`, then the script does not trigger `init()` anymore.

Comment: If I add type="module" the script does not trigger anymore.

Comment: Have you tried taking the .js out of the import statement? i.e. from './logParser' that is how I import files normally.

Comment: Yep. I'm using edge, I have 'main.js' as a <script> In the head tag and I don't want to write the logParser logic inside 'main.js'.

Comment: `loadFile = function () { console.log("file loaded."); };` doesn't this throw an error? I would expect `loadFile: function () { console.log("file loaded."); }`, since it's a property of an object.

Comment: Even if I empty it out it would give the same error. I'm using Edge and the .html and .js files are stored locally on my drive. Could that be it?

Comment: This was all just a clusterfuck because I did read the doc correctly. You need to specify that the script is a module in the <script> tag, as static import does not work otherwise.